# Converting Video into 3 Value Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, video, rgb

I need to write a Python script that converts video into a json array. The final product would look like this:

```
// first frame:
arr1 = [(251, 135, 0), (127, 5, 860), etc]
arr2 = [(251, 135, 0), (127, 5, 860), etc]
arr3 = [(251, 135, 0), (127, 5, 860), etc]
```

Each array represents a single frame of the video, while each sub array represents one pixel of video, stored in RGB values. Does anyone know of a library that allows you to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wow, that's going to be a *big* source file :-)

Comment: Totally! I plan to have the actual videos themselves more like 160 x 90 (pixels) and only a few seconds long, so it should only be a fraction of the size used in 1920 x 1080 or heaven forbid 4K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use OpenCV to process the file. This code, for example, processes one of my 320x180 videos, and prints the first few pixels in each frame in roughly the format you want:

```
# Open up and get first frame (if any).

import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("/home/pax/test320x180.mp4")
okay, frame = cap.read()
fnum = 0
print(f'# Video appears to be {len(frame[0])} x {len(frame)}')

# Process each frame.

while okay:
    fnum += 1
    sep = ' ['
    print(f'arr{fnum} =', end='')
    limit = 3
    for row in frame:
        for pixel in row:
            print(f'{sep}({pixel[0]}, {pixel[1]}, {pixel[2]})', end='')
            sep = ', '
            limit -= 1
            if limit == 0: break
        if limit == 0: break
    if limit == 0: print(', ...', end='')
    print(']')
    okay, frame = cap.read()
```

The output of that is:

```
# Video appears to be 320 x 180
arr1 = [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), ...]
arr2 = [(157, 130, 73), (194, 167, 110), (192, 170, 100), ...]
arr3 = [(157, 130, 73), (194, 167, 110), (192, 170, 100), ...]
arr4 = [(157, 130, 73), (194, 167, 110), (192, 170, 100), ...]
arr5 = [(157, 130, 73), (194, 167, 110), (192, 170, 100), ...]
arr6 = [(157, 130, 73), (194, 167, 110), (192, 170, 100), ...]
arr7 = [(159, 129, 73), (196, 166, 110), (194, 169, 100), ...]
arr8 = [(159, 129, 73), (196, 166, 110), (194, 169, 100), ...]
arr9 = [(159, 129, 73), (196, 166, 110), (194, 169, 100), ...]
arr10 = [(159, 129, 73), (196, 166, 110), (194, 169, 100), ...]
:
arr887 = [(227, 199, 179), (230, 202, 182), (228, 204, 186), ...]
arr888 = [(227, 199, 179), (230, 202, 182), (228, 204, 186), ...]
arr889 = [(227, 201, 181), (229, 203, 183), (229, 205, 187), ...]
arr890 = [(225, 199, 179), (228, 202, 182), (228, 204, 186), ...]
arr891 = [(225, 199, 179), (228, 202, 182), (228, 204, 186), ...]
```

If you're willing to put up with checking the *entire* file (or once you're happy the pixels are correct), just remove all lines containing the `limit` variable.

Comment: I'm getting a variety of errors and after removing line 7 altogether, the script doesn't print any of the output you have mentioned. Of course I did change the directory and video to be one of my own.

Comment: @Aaron, check to see what the first `cap.read()` returns (in `okay`). It may be that your video file is unsupported by CV.

Comment: @Aaron, mp4 is a container format, I believe the embedded codecs can be arbitrary. Regardless of that, it should still be simple to see if it's supported by OpenCV just by checking the `read()` result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenCV to convert each video frame to an 1D array and format that to your liking with further processing.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('numbers.mp4')

while (cap.isOpened()):
    # Get a video frame
    hasFrame, frame = cap.read()


    if hasFrame == True:
        ## Convert BGR to RGB
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        print(frame.ravel())

        #print(frame.shape)
        #print(len(frame.ravel()))
        #print(frame[0][1])

    else:
        break

cap.release()
```

This code will print an array for each frame in, [R G B R G B ...] format. First, R G B corresponds to first pixel and so on.